# How do I feed a string to a function's input statement in Python?

Tags: python, stdin

In python I have a function which has an input statement, and assume that the function is a blackbox so I cannot edit the function. Instead of letting users to type and input, I want to feed a string to the input statement.

I have found a way to do so by starting a subprocess to run the function and feed the string as stdin.

Another approach is just using PIPE.

Is there any purely python way to achieve it?

Comment: If you can override `input` before calling it, you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63522511/8612463

Comment: the situation is unclear, please provide some code to make it easier for us

Comment: You should consider rewriting the function with parameters instead of asking for input. It is a better practice and more reusable if you do so.

Comment: @Malo thanks, but I have mentioned that I don't want to rewrite the function. I know it's a good practice to use parameters instead of inputs, but I just want to find a solution to solve this corner case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a string as stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062895/how-to-use-a-string-as-stdin)

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, as I mentioned, setting stdin is an approach. I want to find a more python way to do so, as some other people answered, for example, overwriting the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the module's function e.g. `mymodule.input = myfunc`, then your function will be called and afterwards just return a string from your function.

```py
# mymodule
def func():
    print(input())
```

```py
# main
import mymodule

def custom():
    return "my custom input"

mymodule.input = custom
mymodule.func()
```

however this *might* need to happen *before* `mymodule` is imported anywhere else. Depending on how the [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is called (e.g. as a global call in a module thus (`import module` already calling it indirectly) vs in a function, when it'd look into the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) which would be patched)

Now, there's an alternative with deeper patching, but we can't do much as [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is a built-in **and** [implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/135cabd328504e1648d17242b42b675cdbd0193b/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2060) (so not much of a patching available :( ). We can, however, utilize a custom [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) such as [`io.StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) by which you can write to own "stdin" (it's not the real process' [STDIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)), just a buffer replacement, but that doesn't matter for this use-case).

Then a simple [`sys.stdin.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write) with rewinding will do (again, **has to** happen before [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is called:

```py
import sys
from io import StringIO
sys.stdin = StringIO()
sys.stdin.write("myinput")
sys.stdin.seek(0)  # rewind, so input() can read
text = input()
print(f"{text=}")
```

Between processes, as you've mentioned, use [`PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE) from [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) or similar module.

Comment: @TongTony Check the answer again, example with `sys.stdin` included.

Answer (score 0):

```
import mymodule
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    @property
    def email(self):
        return f"{name}@gmail.com}"
P = Person("Praddyumn")
mymodule.email = p.email
```

Here `mymodule` is an example of a module that takes `email` as an argument, but in class `Person` we have `email` as a function, but by using the `@property` decorator this function `email` becomes an atribute, so you can use this with pure Python.