# Hardcode/overwrite value for `input()` in python

Tags: python, input, stdin

#### What are the details of your problem?

There are several ways to take external input - stdin, CLI arguments, or files, etc.
In python3, keywords respectively are: `input`, `sys.argv`, `open`.

The most commonly used of these in normal applications is taking input from the `stdin` i.e. either via keyboard, or via shell; the `input()` function in python.

But unlike both the other 2 methods, i don't know the way to automate or hardcode this *within the script* be it for C/C++/Python. Some known ways to (semi) automate input seams to be stdin i.e. `<<<` in bash, or (as told by chatGPT) in configuration files.

This lack of automation makes it very hard while doing any type of coding, be it 
designing for the first time, debugging, or benchmarking/timing.

Replacing the whole input function call with some value may work for less variables, but where lots of variables take input, it becomes laborious to add and remove such substitutes.

---

In continuation of this, I would like to reproduce the setup used by online coding sites like Hackerrank, Coding Ninja etc to test the script against variety of inputs.

*Also to measure or cap it with time and memory limits to overcome the TLEs, but that's outside scope of this question.*

Comment: You can replace `sys.stdin` in python with whatever you like (e.g. `open()`) by direct assignment. Does it suffice?

Comment: One way can be to redefine the `input` function by another one which returns the desired input string.

Comment: (though I admit I don't fully understand your question)

Comment: You could make your "tester" script run the main script using `subprocess.run`, which allows you to specify `stdin`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: @SUTerliakov i tried `sys.stdin = '2\n5\n10'` or `sys.stdin = [2,5,10]` and in the ipython cells, still asked for input. and on the bash shell, it showed error on input() line that 'str' object has no attribute 'readline'

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062895/how-to-use-a-string-as-stdin

Comment: yes @slothrop `sys.stdin = io.StringIO('2\n5\n100')` worked.

Comment: @MichaelButscher i tried this, `def input():
    yield io.StringIO('2')
    yield io.StringIO('5')
    yield io.StringIO('10')` (and also with normal strings), but it showed the error: `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'strip'` as the call was `input().strip()`

Comment: `input` should just return a string. You can create a global variable holding a list of the strings to return and a global variable holding an index into the list what to return next (which is incremented by your `input`).

Comment: `input` is essentially just a convenience wrapper around `sys.stdin.readline`. It could be defined with something like `def input(prompt=""): print(prompt, end=''); line = sys.stdin.readline(); if line == '': raise EOFError; else return line.rstrip('\n')` Note that it is *guaranteed* not to return a value containing a newline: it always returns  a *single* line with the trailing newline stripped. Any replacement needs to abide by this convention, or you run the risk of breaking code that consumes the return value of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the input in the comments with my own observation on them:

##### 1. Directly assign the values to `sys.stdin: io.StringIO` 
 - by @SUTerliakov and @slothrop

Description:

- colon means type annotation.
- confirmed to work on CLI with calls like: `input()`, `input().strip()`, `int( input().strip() )`
- doesn't work from .py source files' `# %%` ipython cells, i.e. still asks for input.
- requires at least *all* the values for the input to be defined, otherwise raise error `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` (very similar to `standard_input` var in [AREPL vscodium extension](https://github.com/Almenon/AREPL-vscode/wiki/Using-AREPL-with-input))
- Example: `sys.stdin = io.StringIO('2\n5\n10')` will supply values to 3 input calls

Refer:

- SO: [How to use a string as stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062895/how-to-use-a-string-as-stdin)
- [docs.py/lib/sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)

##### 2. Redefine `input()` - by @MichaelButscher

- I couldn't get it to work despite trying:

  - give normal string: `return '2\n5\n10'`: 
    `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2\n5\n10'`
  - `AttributeError: 'xxxx' object has no attribute 'strip'` 
    (where xxxx = _io.StringIO or list or generator) when giving io.StringIO or list or yielding string: 
    `return io.StringIO('2\n5\n\10')`: 
    `return ['2','5','10']` 
    `yield '2'; yield '5'; yield '10'` \

##### 3. Use `subprocess.run()` - by @slothrop

Description:

- create a separate runner/tester script, and call the main script from that script using `subprocess.run()` which allows passing std arguments
- while super flexible and extensible ...
- ~~this ain't directly executble on-the-go like shift-enter of `# %%` ipython cells~~ 
  (oh well, ctrl-tab > shift-enter)
- but maybe there's some way to only call some function and not the whole script - if yes, then this can be used to avoid recursion and even define this runner/tester script within the main file itself.

Refer:

- [docs.py/lib/subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: If you want to write a generator function (call it `input_gen`) that yields your desired values, then you can use it as the source of input by doing something like: `g = input_gen(); input = lambda _: next(g)`